# Cannot run angular-google-maps within ionic cordova build to android

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an `ionic` project where one of its pages uses the `angular google maps` directive.  On a browser everything works as it should, however when I emulate the project in android I get the following error on `ADB` catalog:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'google-maps' is not availabl
>   e! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>   I/chromium( 1678): http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/nomod?p0=google-
>   maps

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to look at the link given in your error, I guess it leads you to a very well explained documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=google-%20maps

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi thanks for helping , i saw that link but i know its not badly configured or badly spelled because i am able to run the application in my browser. this only happen when running in simulated android/ios